# Input string was not in a correct format (using SqlDataReader)

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting data from a remote Database, so I don't actually know the column types I'm dealing with. So I was using `dataReader.GetString(X)` as a default. I can save those values into variables, but when actually trying to send the variables into an object constructor it fails (before getting inside the constructor) with an error :  `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` If I can save them to string type variables why does it give an error when trying to use those variables to create an object and not before?

```
        //VARIABLES
        DateTime PreparationDate;
        string ClientId;
        string ClientName;
        string BL;
        string QTD_TOT;
        string QTD_PREP;
        string X_QTD;
        string TAXA;

            string query = GetPreparationsMACPAC;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<PreparationViewModel> shippingsList = new List<PreparationViewModel>();

            PreparationViewModel prep = new PreparationViewModel(new DateTime(), "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {                    
                    PreparationDate = dr.GetDateTime(0);
                    ClientId = dr.GetString(1);
                    ClientName = dr.GetString(2);
                    BL = dr.GetString(3);
                    QTD_TOT = dr.GetString(4);
                    QTD_PREP = dr.GetString(5);
                    X_QTD = dr.GetString(6);
                    TAXA = dr.GetString(7);

                    //THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT IS CORRET (see below)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}", PreparationDate, ClientId, ClientName, BL, QTD_TOT, QTD_PREP, X_QTD, TAXA);

                    //FAILS HERE
                    try
                    {
                        prep = new PreparationViewModel(PreparationDate, ClientId, ClientName, BL, QTD_TOT, QTD_PREP, X_QTD, TAXA);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }

                    shippingsList.Add(prep);
                }
            }
```

**OUTPUT**(1*Datetime + 7*Strings Seperated by ",")

```
09/04/2021 00:00:00,92843160002,RENAULT MONTAJE VALLADOLID,506653,120,120,0.000,1.0000000
```

**CLASS MODEL**

```
    public class PreparationViewModel
    {
        public PreparationViewModel()
        {

        }

        public PreparationViewModel(DateTime preparationDate, string clientId, string clientName, string transportDocumentId,
            string totalQuantity, string preparedQuantity, string xQuantity, string complianceRate)
        {
            //BREAKPOINT IS SET, NOT REACHED FROM THE TRY/CATCH CODE
            PreparationDate = preparationDate;
            ClientId = clientId;
            ClientName = clientName;
            TransportDocumentId = transportDocumentId;
            TotalQuantity = Int16.Parse(totalQuantity);
            PreparedQuantity = Int16.Parse(preparedQuantity);
            XQuantity = float.Parse(xQuantity);
            ComplianceRate = float.Parse(complianceRate);
        }

        public DateTime PreparationDate {get;set;}
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string TransportDocumentId { get; set; }
        public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
        public int PreparedQuantity { get; set; }
        public float XQuantity { get; set; }
        public float ComplianceRate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If it fails before getting into the constructor - it means it fails inside `PreparationViewModel`'s static constructor or during initialisation of one of its static members

Comment: @torvin, How so? I'm able, for example, to create a `PreparationsViewModel(new DateTime(),"0","0","0","0","0","0","0")` with no troubles; so I'm not quite sure of what do you mean.

Comment: If you are able to do that then this statement is false: "it fails (before getting inside the constructor)". Try setting a breakpoint inside the constructor. Also a full stack trace would be helpful

Comment: And the code of the constructor itself.

Comment: It *sounds* like `PreparationViewModel` has some code in the constructor that is parsing values from strings; we can't see that code, so we can't really comment - but: my first guess would be "locale". The first thing to say is that you shouldn't really store values in a database as strings if they could be primitives - if you *can* store it as an int/float/decimal/whatever: do that instead, and don't touch strings. But if you somehow have to use strings, you need to ensure that the parse code uses the right locale, otherwise: bad things. Is "100.000" one hundred, or one hundred thousand?

Comment: @torvin I do have a breakpoint in the constructor, It is never reached from the code inside `try/catch`, so my statement "before getting inside the constructor". Going to edit my question to include the constructor nonetheless

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm getting data from a remote database so I don´t know exactly the column types, can only assume them from the values. I tried to read them as strings because it felt the best default way to do it.

Comment: _Int16.Parse(totalQuantity);_ assumes a string (_totalQuantity_) that is convertible to an integer. An empty string is not convertible to an integer. And the same is true for the float.Parse with the added complexity of the locale convention. Use Int32.TryParse and float.TryParse

Comment: And just to check if the reason of your problem are those conversions just comment the last  4 last lines in the constructor and see if the exception disappears

Comment: @Steve Commenting those lines solved it. I thought the error couldn't be on the constructor because the breakpoint didn't get "hit" (it still doesn't, and I don't understand why, from other calls said breakpoint is "hit"). Thank you. Now I know exactly the source of the error and can work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting data from a remote database so I don´t know exactly the column types

In that scenario, your best bet is probably something like:

```cs
short prepQty = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetValue(5), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(or if you don't want the invariant culture: replace with whatever culture you *do* want; if the values are strings and you don't know the culture: you've already lost the battle)

This will handle more data types *and* have better defined semantics when handling strings. It would be advisable to keep the read/parse code in the code that handles the reader, and have the `PreparationViewModel` just take the parsed value (the `short`).